# SonarQube "Do not define components during render" with MUI/TS but can't send component as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, sonarqube, react-typescript

I am getting the following error during sonarqube scan:

> Do not define components during render. React will see a new component type on every render and destroy the entire subtree’s DOM nodes and state. Instead, move this component definition out of the parent component “SectionTab” and pass data as props. If you want to allow component creation in props, set allowAsProps option to true.

[image]

I understand that it says that I should send the component as a prop from the parent, but I don't want to send the icon everytime that I want to use this component, is there another way to get this fixed?

```tsx
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faAngleDown } from "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons/faAngleDown";

const AngleIcon = ({ props }: { props: any }) => {
  return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      {...props}
      sx={{ marginRight: "10px" }}
      icon={faAngleDown}
      size="xs"
    />
  );
};

const SectionTab = () => {
  return (
    <Select
      id="course_type"
      readOnly={true}
      IconComponent={(props) => <AngleIcon props={props} />}
      variant="standard"
      defaultValue="cr"
      disableUnderline
    />
  );
};

export default SectionTab;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What can you do:

1. Send the component as the prop:

   ```
   IconComponent={AngleIcon}
   ```
2. If you need to pass anything to the component on the fly, you can wrap it with `useCallback`:

   ```
   const SectionTab = () => {
       const IconComponent = useCallback(props => <AngleIcon props={props} />, []);

      return (
        <Select
          id="course_type"
          readOnly={true}
          IconComponent={IconComponent}
          variant="standard"
          defaultValue="cr"
          disableUnderline
        />
      );
    };
   ```

This would generate a stable component, but it's pretty redundant unless you need to pass anything else, and not via the `props`. In that case, a new component would be generated every time that external value changes, which would make it unstable again. You can use refs to pass values without generating a new component, but the component's tree won't be re-rendered to reflect the change in the ref.

```
const SectionTab = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  
  const IconComponent = useCallback(
    props => <AngleIcon props={props} value={value} />
  , []);

  return (
    <Select
      id="course_type"
      readOnly={true}
      IconComponent={IconComponent}
      variant="standard"
      defaultValue="cr"
      disableUnderline
    />
  );
};
```